# What is encryption method for the 3rd part of the Kryptos text?

Tags: cryptography, encryption, cryptanalysis

http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptos_%28sculpture%29
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kryptos

I read the Kryptos wikipedia page, is says it's crypted with a "modular transposition of lines and columns".

What is that ? How hard it is for a non-cryptanalist ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of useful articles written about Kryptos, that are very interesting to the amateur cryptographer such as myself - your best bet for this particular question is probably [Frank Corr's post on derkeiler](http://www.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/sci.crypt/2006-02/msg00516.html).

> It uses two grids of dimensions 21 x
>   16 and 28 x 12. The plaintext ends up
>   being written into the first grid by
>   row, starting at the top row, and
>   removed by column, starting with the
>   last column and moving backward. It is
>   then run through the second grid in
>   the same way.

It is much easier to understand when described like that.